# How to express these sets mathematically?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm conducting an optimization where I have a set of ordered pairs, L. In my case:

```
L = (1,2) (2,1) etc.
```

I also have a set Wplus which is the combination of all possible combination of the ordered pairs.

```
Wplus = (1,1) (1,2) (2,2) (2,1) etc.
```

I also want a set which is like that in L, but the "reversed". In my optimization I have that L = (i,j) for a Company j and facility i. In this set, R, I want the "Company part" constant, but change the i for those of other companies. In this example:

```
R = (2,2) (1,1)
```

How do I express these mathematically? What I've done thus far is to define Wplus as:

```
Wplus = I union J
```

Where I is the set of all facility locations i and J the set of all companies j. It "feels" like this is not the correct way to do this when handling tuples, or ordered pairs? Is it correct to say that it is a union of these?

What I have done with R is:

```
R = Wplus \ (set difference) L
```

but then again, is it correct to use set unions and differences when having tuples? Is there some other more "elegant" way of achieving the definitions of the intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets do not care about order, and even merges identical elements. Union of two sets likewise just dumps all elements in both sets into one big set, where identical elements are really identical. So $\{1,2,3\} \cup \{1,3,5\} = \{1,2,3,5\}$. What you want is the cartesian product $I \times J$ which can be understood as the set of pairs with first element from $I$ and second element from $J$.

If $I = \{1,2\}$ and $J = \{a,b,z\}$ then $I \times J = \{(1,a),(1,b),(1,z),(2,a),(2,b),(2,z)\}$. Now you restrict $L \subseteq I \times J$. For example, we could have $L = \{(1,a),(2,b),(1,z)\}$.

I think you typed "other companies" when you meant "other facilities". You also didn't specify whether $L$ has only one pair for each second element (company), so your question is not well-defined. I will assume that a company may use more than one facility, and you want to specify pairs for the unused facilities. Mathematically, for each $j \in J$ you want all the pairs $(i,j)$ with $i \in I$ that do not appear in $L$. When you collect all these together you get:

$\{ (i,j) : i \in I \land j \in J \land (i,j) \notin L \}$   ["$\land$" means "and"]

This has a shorter expression:

$(I \times J) \setminus L$   [everything in $I \times J$ but excluding anything in $L$]

If you specifically want the collection for a single company $j$ it would be:

$\{ (i,j) : i \in I \land (i,j) \notin L \}$

Comment: Thank you! Yes you interpreted my lack of information correct. A follow-up question, you defined basically a set of tuples which is not present in L, which is understandable. Is there a way to define the initial set L neatly? Now, I've basically said that "L is a set of ordered pairs (i,j) where i represents the supply facilities owned by Company j".

Comment: @GustavDanell: How to define $L$ unless we know what $L$ is defined as? Your last sentence in your comment is sufficient. There will always be an interface between the real-world and mathematical language, and it will necessarily be in some natural language such as English.